# Is there a conditional where statement in SQLite?

Tags: sql, typescript, sqlite, better-sqlite3

I have a Todo application with a database for the todos. It contains a column *done* which will be set to false or true. Now I want to filter the data by *all* or *unfinished*. So either done is irrelevant or it has to be *false*.

I am using SQLite3 in a TypeScript application. Currently I do this by using string templates but I'd prefer an SQL-based solution.

```
db.prepare(`
  select 
    rowid as id, 
    title, 
    description
  from todo
    ${selectAll ? '' : 'where done = 0'}
    limit ?
    offset ?
`).all(limit, offset);
```

My idea was to use the `CASE` clause but it seems not to work around the `WHERE` clause.

Is there any better solution?

`selectAll` is a TypeScript variable that is set depending on the query parameters of the app.

**Output when `selectAll` is false**

```
id | title             | description          | done
1  | Clean the kitchen | as the title says... | 1
2  | Do the shopping   | potatoes, tomatoes   | 0
3  | Program stuff     | Todo app             | 1
```

**Output when `selectAll` is true**

```
id | title             | description          | done
2  | Do the shopping   | potatoes, tomatoes   | 0
```

Comment: Can you edit to add the output you want ?

Comment: @DanielE. sure. One moment.

Comment: Why "better"? What is the problem with using different SQL for different queries? (Please note that you will have even more queries when you modify the app later.)

Comment: @CL. That is true, yes. With better I meant pure sql based solutions for that, to prevent any attacks. I don't think that there's a way to exploit my conditional statement above, but when I to modify it later on and I continue to use conditional statements for that, it may affect the app's security.

Comment: You need parameters (`?`) for any values whose textual representation is controlled by the user, but only for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean logic:

```
where ? = '' or done = 0
```

Comment: That's a nice solution. Thanks.